# My PYTHONPATH was deleted by a package. How can I recover the PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda

My PYTHONPATH environment variable was accidentally deleted by a package during some testing. I don't have a back up of the path variable, but now I can't import any third party packages into python because I'm missing all the paths that were previously there.

Is there a way to recover just the standard PYTHONPATH variables?

I'm using Anaconda distribution with Python 3.6.
Windows 10.

I tried system restore, but this has failed for my only restore points, another issue I have to sort out.

Comment: As far as I know, the standard `PYTHONPATH` environment variable has nothing in it. Whatever you put in there was custom...

Comment: Yes, thank you. Its been so long that I added these custom variables I forgot what was in there. Just wondering if there is a way to restore what was there before they got accidentally deleted.

Comment: Nope, probably not. Instead, prefer environments, particularly if you're using conda anyways